# Problema 401 del Proyecto Euler en Maxima

Tags: matemáticas, maxima

Enunciado del problema:

Los divisores de 6 son 1,2,3 y 6.
La suma de los cuadrados de estos números es:

1 + 4 + 9 + 9 + 36 = 50

Permita que `sigma2(n)` represente la suma de los cuadrados de los divisores de n.

Así, `sigma2 (6) = 50`.

Y `sumas_sigma2(n)` es la suma de todos los sigma2, menores o iguales a n. Por ejemplo,

`sumas_sigma2(6) = 113`

Esto es lo que yo he programado:

```
/* sigma2(n) devuelve la suma de los divisores de n elevados al
   cuadrado. Por ejemplo,
   sigma2(6);
    50
*/

sigma2(n) :=
   divsum(n,2)$

sumas_sigma2(n) :=
    lreduce("+", makelist(sigma2(k), k, 1, n))$
```

Pero, es muy poco eficiente. Pues necesito calcular `sumas_sigma(10^8)` y mi algoritmo no es capaz de calcularlo, en menos de un minuto.

Comment: en lugar de usar `lreduce` y `makelist`, probablemente sea mucho mas rapido algo como `sum(divsum(k,2), k, 1, n);`, pero como la mayoria de los problemas de project euler las soluciones optimas requieren pensamiento matematico para evitar los calculos innecesarios

Comment: @lois6b @Klaimmore Pregunte en Mathematics, pero la solución que me daban al problema era la que había puesto yo. Asimismo, me equivoqué aquí, pues el dato que me piden `sumas_sigma(10^8)`. Sigue sin funcionar. ¿Se os ocurre alguna eficiencia?

Comment: en cuanto a codigo la unica eficiencia seria usar `memoization` pero no se si Maxima lo soporta...

Comment: @lois6b Por cierto, ¿qué es `memoization`?

Comment: @lois6b  Quizás esto tenga algo que ver, pero no estoy seguro:  https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/mailman/message/35344545/

Comment: @aprendiendo-a-programar memorization se aplica a funciones que siempre dan los mismos resultados, como fibonacci en ese enlace y guarda los valores así la segunda vez que se ejecuta es instantánea aquellos resultados ya calculados.

Comment: Entonces, se puede implementar en este caso? @lois6b

Comment: @aprendiendo-a-programar En ese enlace que pusiste hay alguna función para memorization en fib.... Seguramente se pueda adaptar para tu sigma

Comment: @lois6b  Problema logrado. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Lo ha calculado en 5 segundos. Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: @aprendiendo-a-programar oh! Estupendo. Puedes redactar una respuesta? Así yo y otros podremos aprender el cómo quedó la solución :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tras la magnífica ayuda de distintos usuarios de stackOverflow y Mathematics, he llegado a la siguiente solución, que es capaz de resolver el problema en un buen intervalo de tiempo (5 secs - 7 secs)

```
sigma2(n) :=
   divsum(n,2)$

sumas_sigma2(n) :=
    sum(sumas_sigma2(k), k, 1, n)$
    memoize(sumas_sigma2);
```

Una vez más, muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Vaya! Que sencillo parece ahora. Me alegra que lo solucionaras. Recuerda cuando te lo permita marcarla como aceptada